# Remove country & state dropdown in Woocommerce Checkout & replace with regular Input box

Tags: woocommerce, state, checkout, country

I would like to change my checkout page in Woocommerce, so instead of a dropdown Country menu and a dropdown State/Region menu, I have simple Input boxes just like Name, Address, etc.

I haven't figured out how to fix this without crashing woocommerce.
Does anyone know how to change Country & State to work as normal input boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Checkout Field Editor](http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-checkout-field-editor/).

Comment: Wow that worked perfect. Very simple. Had no idea it existed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'billing_state_remove', 900, 1);
function billing_state_remove($fields)
{
    unset($fields['billing_state']);
    unset($fields['billing_country']);
};
```

Comment: Any idea how can i make this ONLY to happen on specific countries? In my case, the state field does not show up in France, but i need it to be visible as a text box, but state field does not show up at all for France.

Comment: @AndresMolinaPerez-Tome inside of `$fields['billing_state']`  & `$fields['billing_country']` is a field called `country`, that you can check for its value and act accordingly..